# using HTML <font> in QLabel won't work after '\n'

Tags: python, html, pyqt, pyqt5

I'm trying to make a multi-line Label for logging. I want the Error, debug, and info lines to be different colors, but after \n the `<font color="blue">something </font>` won't work.

I'm using python 3.6 and pyqt5

examples to reproduce:

**WORKS**

```
label.setText('something <font color="blue">Hello</font><font color="red"> World</font something2')
```

**DOESNT WORK**

```
setText('some \n thing <font color="blue">Hello</font><font color="red"> World</font something2')
```

is that supposed to be like that and I'm just using it wrong? is there a workaround?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What happens is that when placing "\n" Qt interprets that what you want to place is plain text so the HTML tags are not used, instead you must use`<br>`:

```
label.setText('some <br> thing <font color="blue">Hello</font><font color="red"> World</font something2')
```

[image]